# Toggle element class on checkbox state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The class hidden should be toggling based on if the checkbox is checked. One of the drop-down menus should be hidden and the other be displayed.

maybe my ternary operator isn't set up properly.

Thanks in advance.

```js
function toggleButton() {
    var toggler      = $("input[name='toggler']").prop('checked');
    var awardOptions = $('#awardOptions');
    var yearOptions  = $('#yearOptions');
    var awardShow    = awardOptions.removeClass('hidden');
    var yearShow     = yearOptions.removeClass('hidden');
    var awardHide  = awardOptions.addClass('hidden');
    var yearHide   = yearOptions.addClass('hidden');
   console.log(toggler);
    return (toggler)  ? (awardShow,yearHide) : (awardHide, yearShow);
  }
  
  $('#toggler').on('click', function(){
    toggleButton();
  });
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggleWrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" class="dn" name="toggler" id="toggler" checked/>
  <label for="toggler" class="toggle">
    <span class="toggle__handler"></span>
  </label>
</div>      
<div class="inputBox" id="filter">
  <div class="dropdown hidden" id="yearOptions">
    <select id="hof-year">
      <option value="0">Choose a Year</option>
      <option value="2016">2016</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown" id="awardOptions">
    <select id="hof-accomp">
      <option value="0">Choose an Award</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the function I'm using to trigger the toggleButton function.

```
$('#toggler').on('click', function(){
   toggleButton();
});
```

Comment: Please show your toggleButton method.

Comment: What ternary operator? There's none in your source, and you mentioned Codepen (before edits), but there is no link…

Comment: @Scott Marcus deleted the link.

Comment: Edited it back in. @cpt-crunchy Don't link to code on 3rd party sites as those links can die over time and then your question here is meaningless. Include all relevant code in your question as a code snippet as I have done for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `var awardShow = awardOptions.toggleClass('hidden');` instead of using `addClass` or `removeClass`.

```js
  $('#toggler').on('click', function(){
    $('#awardOptions, #yearOptions').toggleClass('hidden');
  });
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggleWrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" class="dn" name="toggler" id="toggler" checked/>
  <label for="toggler" class="toggle">
    <span class="toggle__handler"></span>
  </label>
</div>      
<div class="inputBox" id="filter">
  <div class="dropdown hidden" id="yearOptions">
    <select id="hof-year">
      <option value="0">Choose a Year</option>
      <option value="2016">2016</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown" id="awardOptions">
    <select id="hof-accomp">
      <option value="0">Choose an Award</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not `$('#awardOptions, #yearOptions').toggleClass('hidden');` :D

Comment: I beat you to it. @DanielOrmeño